# O que são/fazem essas dependências?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependências, pom

Comecei a trabalhar com programação faz umas 3 semanas no máximo, me deram o código e eu tô mega perdido. 
Até ontem eu só sabia dar saídas no terminal do Eclipse, e agora tenho todas essas bibliotecas (acho que é esse o nome) e gostaria de saber o que elas são e pra que servem.

Elas estavam no arquivo pom.xml.

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>

<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>

<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>

<groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
<artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>

<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>

<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>

<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>

<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>

<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>

<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essas dependências são nada mais nada menos que bibliotecas externas que a aplicação vai utilizar.

Por exemplo, ao que parece essa aplicação usa o Spring Boot. Assim, foi necessário adicionar ao projeto as bibliotecas do Spring Boot e algumas outras mais como o conector do banco de dados MySQL, etc.

No Java você tem as chamadas classes e interfaces nativas, que são aquelas disponíveis no JDK/JRE. Mas ao usar um framework como o Spring, se faz então necessário adicionar as classes/interfaces referentes ao Spring. E elas estão disponíveis através de bibliotecas externas (dependências).

Comment: Mas e as demais bibliotecas? Tipo org.apache.commons-commns.io ou com.zaxxer-HikariCP?

Comment: Cada uma delas faz referencia a algo que será usado dentro do projeto. As vezes também, uma biblioteca do Spring precisa de outras bibliotecas externas que não são do Spring. Por exemplo a **junit** é para testes unitários, **jstl** é para as páginas JSP, **HikariCP** é um pool de conexões para banco de dados, ... Teria que pegar o nome delas e buscar no google para ver exatamente o que cada uma delas faz.